# Last element of the array is always NaN even though I used Number() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, csv, for-loop

Kindly help me investigate my `function` below since I'm stuck and still having a hard time figuring it out.

All is well **until** it reaches the last column on the `nested FOR loop`. The **last column of each row**'s values are only `"0"`. However, I used the `Number()` function to make the **cell values**`(i.e. "0")` a `number` but I **keep on getting** `NaN` for the **last element** of the `SUM` & `COUNT` arrays.

`colCount = 326` while `rowCount = 374`.

`sum.length` and `count.length` should **really** be `ONLY 325` since the `headers` are **unnecessary** and the first column is **just composed of time stamps**. I was able to `.push(0)` successfully **until** the `nested FOR loop` **changed** the result of the last element to `NaN`.

```
function processDataToDictionary(csv) {
    var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);

    var csvArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < allTextLines.length - 1; i++) {
        var row = allTextLines[i].split(',');

        csvArray.push(row);
    }

    var colCount = csvArray[0].length;
    var rowCount = csvArray.length;

    //Arrays of values
    var count = [];
    var sum = [];
    var average = [];
    var headers = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < colCount; i++) {
        var current = csvArray[0][i].replace(/"/g, '');
        sum.push(0);
        count.push(0);

        headers[i] = current;
    }

    for (let i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {

        for (let j = 1; j < colCount; j++) {
            // Remove the quotes from your array
            current = csvArray[i][j].replace(/"/g, '');

            // Added the Method IsNullOrWhiteSpace
            if (!isNullOrWhitespace(current)) {
                // Parse as double not int to account for dec. values
                sum[j] += Number(current);
                count[j]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        average.push((sum[i] + 0.0) / count[i]);
    }

    for (let i = 1; i < colCount; i++) {
     // create an empty array

        dictionary[headers[i]] = average[i];
    }

    return dictionary;

}

function isNullOrWhitespace(input) {

    if (input == " ") {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an input (argument) for the function, so that I can run it here on the input and reproduce the problem? Is the input too large? Could you maybe upload it somewhere?

Comment: From what you said, I'm guessing the problem with the `sum` Array can only be here: `sum[j] += Number(current);` . I'm guessing there is something wrong with the `headers` last element, but it's hard to know without knowing what the `csv`string is like. If you could give an example of the `csv`, it would help a lot

Comment: Hi @flen, here is a link to the `csv` file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzZ5wr0I2306SU5DdXF1b21IU2c Really stuck, please help. Thanks!

Comment: @flen same thing happens also at `count` array :( strange

Comment: by the way, the `isNullOrWhitespace` is undefined here, so probably what you have is: `undefined` + `0` (or another number) will always equal NaN. Could you please post this method or could this be the bug in the code?

Comment: @flen, I've added the method in the question now. I'm also using the `FileReader` API when reading the `csv`

Comment: I think your IsNullOr... function has a problem with its logic. `null` evaluates to `false`, which is not what you want?JS has no dictionaries like Python, one must use Objects. NodeJS correctly tells me you haven't defined `dictionary`. Please define it like this: `dictionary = {};`

Comment: `JS` array could be made with keys and values. If you'd check the `csv`, there would be some **blank** cells, that is why I included the `IsNullorWhitespace` method. I declared the `dictionary = {};` like that also since the `keys` are `strings` @flen

Comment: It's true, arrays could have Objects inside them (an Array is an Object (typeof Array == Object), but the keys are ints in order ("0", "1", "2", etc), but it's easier to just make an Object. Besides, if I'm not mistaken Arrays need the `.push`method or similar. All I'm getting as output is one Object with one key (`"\\VD100971\System\Processor Queue Length"`) and a NaN value. Is this what you are getting too?

Comment: Exactly! Though the **right** value for the `key` `"\\VD100971\System\Processor Queue Length"` is `0`. But it is giving `NaN` instead. I've cross-checked it with our old and slow working VBA program since this project I'm coding is the automation of it. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142252/discussion-between-flen-and-jpaulpunzalan). I don't know if you're OK with chat and if it's working for you, please let me know here if anything goes wrong

Comment: Try `replace(/[^\d]/g, '')`. Possibility is there is some unwanted character like `\r\n`

Comment: Found your bug:) (This time it's true), please see my answer. Regards

Comment: @Rajesh very last element is still NaN :-/

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan can you print the last value and it's length as strong?

Comment: @Rajesh Hi Rajesh, we've figured it out just now. It's just that the `sum` and `count` were an `element` short of the `csvArray` :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you a dictionary (Object) with the columns names as keys and numbers that appear to be the correct averages as values. But one must still check whether there is a fault in the logic somewhere and the averages are not correct in fact.

```
function processDataToDictionary(csv) {

function isNullOrWhitespace(input) {

    if (input === " ") {

        return true;

    } else if (input === null) {

        return true;

    //} else if (input === undefined) {

        //return true;

    }   else {

        return false;
    }
}


var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);

    var csvArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < allTextLines.length - 1; i++) {
        var row = allTextLines[i].split(',');

        csvArray.push(row);
    }

    var colCount = csvArray[0].length;
    var rowCount = csvArray.length;

    //Arrays of values
    var count = [];
    var sum = [];
    var average = [];
    var headers = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < colCount; i++) {
        var current = csvArray[0][i].replace(/"/g, '');
        sum.push(0);
        count.push(0);

        headers[i] = current;
    }

    /**** I added these two lines ****/
    sum.push(0);
    count.push(0);

for (let i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {

        for (let j = 1; j < colCount ; j++) {

            // Remove the quotes from your array
            current = csvArray[i][j].replace(/"/g, '');

            // Added the Method IsNullOrWhiteSpace
            if (!isNullOrWhitespace(current)) {
                // Parse as double not int to account for dec. values
                sum[j] += Number(current);
                count[j]++;
            }
        }
    }


     for (let i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        average.push((sum[i] + 0.0) / count[i]);
    }


// I added this line:           
dictionary = {};    

 for (let i = 1; i < colCount; i++) {

        dictionary[headers[i]] = average[i];
    }


    return dictionary;

}
```

Let me know if this works out for you. You can loop through the values with: `for (let key in dictionary) {console.log("key: " + key + " , value: " + dictionary[key]);}` . Regards!

Comment: but it just removed the very last element `System\Processor Queue Length`

Comment: I've looked into the other columns that have the same exact values as the last column and they worked, giving out `0` as a result. There must be really something with the last elements of arrays mhmmm

Comment: The problem is that the second for loop would make `sum` and `count` length shorter by one element. Then when the summing loop would run, it wouldn't find any value at last position (because length -=1 ), and would get `undefined`. Then the sum + undefined would return `NaN`

Comment: Exactly!!! I also figured that out **NOW**! Haha bro revert you edits back so that I could mark it as an answer! :)

Comment: OK, I'm glad I could finally help:)

Comment: `sum.push(0)` and `count.push(0)` added lines yesterday were already perfect! Awesome! Thanks a million!

Comment: No problem!:) though I think this version now is neater (this way, header[0] != undefined), but both work alright